# Is Moksha eternal? (Rig Veda)

Tags: upanishads, rig-veda, moksha, dayananda-saraswati, samkhya

Dayananda Saraswati once cited Rig Veda 1.24.2, Samkhya Darshan 1.159, and Mundaka Upanishad 3.2.6 to suggest that Moksha is not eternal. Does that contradict Gita? Comments?

Comment: Where did you find the exact sources quoted by Swami Dayanand ?
Also what reasons did he state for Moksha **not** being eternal??

Comment: Please mention the source where Dayānanda Sarasvatī says so. Also R̥g Veda 1.24.2 doesn't talk about mokṣa. 

*We will recall the dear name of the god Agni, of the first of the
immortals.
He will return us to great Aditi. I would see my father and mother.*

Comment: Here in 1.24, the first deity invoked is Agni, whose presence introduces the ritual that
addresses the plight of the sacrificers. The poet already signals the purpose of
his hymn and rite by asking which god will return his people to Aditi, to the
“Guiltlessness” that the goddess embodies. Aditi is the mother of the Ādityas, and
therefore reference to her leads to mention of the poet’s own mother and father.
The poet implies that because of some offense he might die before his father and
mother. That would be tragic and unnatural, since children should not predecease
their parents.

Comment: Coming to III.2.6 in Muṇḍaka Upaniṣad (trans. Gambhirananda), it says
"*Those to whom the entity presented by vedāntic knowledge has become fully ascertained, and who endeavor assiduously with the help of Yoga of monasticism, become pure in mind. At the supreme moment of final departure all of them become 
identified with the Supreme Immortality in the worlds that are Brahman, and they become freed on every side.* 
This clearly shows the eternal nature of mokṣa, and so the two texts you stated don't align with what you said.

Comment: Sāṅkhya darśana is just the name of the school, not the name of the text. If you mean Sāṅkhyakārikā, that has less than 80 verses. There is no 159th verse in it or 1.159